# Draw lines on chartSeries in Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

This works fine:

```
getSymbols("EBAY") 
chartSeries(EBAY,TA=NULL, theme="white")
addTA(EMA(Cl(EBAY)), on=1, col=6)
abline(h=50, col = 6)
```

But this plots the `chartSeries` but doesn't plot the horizontal line.  Not sure what I'm missing.

```
S <- as.xts(read.zoo(text="date,open,high,low,close,volume
2017-03-10 18:00:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,1
2017-03-10 18:01:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,8
2017-03-10 18:02:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,2
2017-03-10 18:03:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,3
2017-03-10 18:04:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,68
2017-03-10 18:05:00,442.50,442.50,442.50,442.50,20
2017-03-10 18:06:00,442.25,442.25,442.25,442.25,10
2017-03-10 18:07:00,442.50,442.50,442.25,442.25,3
2017-03-10 18:08:00,442.25,442.50,442.25,442.50,2
2017-03-10 18:09:00,442.25,442.25,442.25,442.25,38",
FUN=paste, FUN2=as.POSIXct, header=TRUE, sep=","))

chartSeries(S, theme = chartTheme("white"), type = "candle") #subset = m,TA = NULL)
abline(h=442.3, col = 6) 
#segments(0, 442.3, 90, 442.3)
```

Comment: Charles, can you provide a piece of code to replicate S

Answer (score 4):

Your first example works because there is only one plot drawn on the device (the OHLC candles). The second example doesn't work because the device includes two plots, the OHLC candles and the lower volume bar graph.

If you want to add lines to a `chartSeries` using something like `abline`, you should use `addLines`.

```
chartSeries(S, theme=chartTheme("white"), type="candle")
addLines(h=442.3, col=6)
```

Comment: Yes, that is excellent but now I have another issue.  Multiple addLines() commands seem to show only the last line drawn.

Comment: @CharlesStangor: works fine for me in an interactive session at the top level.  My guess is that you're calling `chartSeries` in a function or loop and need to wrap the calls in `plot`.

Comment: I'm in a shiny renderPlot() function.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrap the calls in plot."  I thought plot was a separate library.